# How to make force layout graph in D3.js responsive to screen/browser size

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js, force-layout

I have a graph using force layout, but it has a fixed width `w` and height `h`:

```
var svg = d3.select("#viz").append("svg")
            .attr("id", "playgraph")
            .attr("width", w)
            .attr("height", h)

var force = d3.layout.force()
              .nodes(nodes)
              .links(links)
              .charge(-1600)
              .linkDistance(45)
              .size([w, h]);
```

which results in a svg graph that does not scale or down despite of changes in screen or browser window size. In order to make it responsive (i.e. automatically resizes itself), I tried using `viewBox` and `preserveAspectRatio` attributes:

```
var svg = d3.select("#viz").append("svg")
            .attr("id", "playgraph")
            .attr("width", w)
            .attr("height", h)
            .attr("viewBox", "0, 0, 600, 400")
            .attr("preserveAspectRatio", "xMidYMid meet");
```

Unfortunately, this didn't work as nothing happens when I adjust the browser window size. I wonder if the `.size([w, h])` of the force graph has anything to do with this.

Please shed some light on how to use `viewBox` and `preserveAspectRatio` attributes with force layout graphs.

Comment: You may want to also attach your redraw function to `window.onresize`

Comment: This question is fairly old, but for those who find it useful, you may also want to consider also restricting the nodes to a bounded box. On resize, the nodes will stay on screen. Example: http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1129492

Answer (score 63, accepted):

The problem is not within `.size()`, it's that you are stating the SVG dimensions in `.attr("width", w) .attr("height", h)`. Remove these two attributes and you'll get it right...

```
var svg = d3.select("#viz").append("svg")
            .attr("id", "playgraph")
             //better to keep the viewBox dimensions with variables
            .attr("viewBox", "0 0 " + w + " " + h )
            .attr("preserveAspectRatio", "xMidYMid meet");
```

http://jsfiddle.net/aaSjd/

Comment: thanks! So now the svg image resizes. However, without setting `attr("width", ...)` and `attr("height", ...)`, the width/height of the image seems to be the width/height of current browser window. Is there any way I can set these two dimensions of the `svg` element somewhere else, without affecting `viewBox` and `preserveAspectRatio` attributes?

Comment: `<style type="text/css">svg {display: block; width: 80%; margin: 0 auto;}</style>` should get you started.

Comment: Just a warning ; `viewBox` attribute is case-sensitive! Notice it is should be `camelCase`. Using an attribute `viewbox` will not work. Also crosslinking other similar questions/answers: 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9400615/whats-the-best-way-to-make-a-d3-js-visualisation-layout-responsive
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44833788/making-svg-container-100-width-and-height-of-parent-container-in-d3-v4-instead/44848367#44848367

Answer (score 10):

The solution shown here: http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3355967 worked well for me!

```
window.addEventListener('resize', resize); 

function resize() {
    var width = window.innerWidth, height = window.innerHeight;
    svg.attr("width", width).attr("height", height);
    force.size([width, height]).resume();
}
```

Make sure to run resize() after you have appended all your lines, nodes etc as well.

Answer (score 6):

Duopixel is very close to what I needed, except I don't know why he nested two `<g>` elements and attached the event listeners to the outermost `<g>` (also requiring an invisible rectangle behind everything to make the g react to events over its whole space).

It's easier to attach the listeners to the `<svg>` itself and then you only need one internal `<g>`.

Here is my full-screen force-directed example:

```
var width = 1000,
    height = 1000;

var color = d3.scale.category20();

var svg = d3.select("body")
    .append("svg")
      .attr({
        "width": "100%",
        "height": "100%"
      })
      .attr("viewBox", "0 0 " + width + " " + height )
      .attr("preserveAspectRatio", "xMidYMid meet")
      .attr("pointer-events", "all")
    .call(d3.behavior.zoom().on("zoom", redraw));

var vis = svg
    .append('svg:g');

function redraw() {
  vis.attr("transform",
      "translate(" + d3.event.translate + ")"
      + " scale(" + d3.event.scale + ")");
}

function draw_graph(graph) {
  var force = d3.layout.force()
      .charge(-120)
      .linkDistance(30)
      .nodes(graph.nodes)
      .links(graph.links)
      .size([width, height])
      .start();

  var link = vis.selectAll(".link")
      .data(graph.links)
      .enter().append("line")
      .attr("class", "link")
      .style("stroke-width", function(d) { return Math.sqrt(d.value); });

  var node = vis.selectAll(".node")
      .data(graph.nodes)
      .enter().append("circle")
      .attr("class", "node")
      .attr("r", 5)
      .style("fill", function(d) { return color(d.group); })
      .call(force.drag);

  node.append("title")
      .text(function(d) { return d.name; });

  force.on("tick", function() {
    link.attr("x1", function(d) { return d.source.x; })
        .attr("y1", function(d) { return d.source.y; })
        .attr("x2", function(d) { return d.target.x; })
        .attr("y2", function(d) { return d.target.y; });

    node.attr("cx", function(d) { return d.x; })
        .attr("cy", function(d) { return d.y; });
  });
};

draw_graph(data);
```