# Make D3.js width and height 100%

Tags: d3.js, svg

How do I make an svg the entire height and width of a page. The below code creates an svg with a width of 1411 and height of 150. I understand that d3 has a default height of 150. But, I am setting it in the code to 100%. How do I set it to 100% of the width and height of the page?

```
var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", "100%")
    .attr("height", "100%");
```

Comment: Is what you are after answered in this [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44833788/making-svg-container-100-width-and-height-of-parent-container-in-d3-v4-instead)? [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9400615/whats-the-best-way-to-make-a-d3-js-visualisation-layout-responsive) deals with the broader issue of having a responsive D3.js SVG.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One very simple way to do this would be to [get the `window`'s width and height](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3437786/get-the-size-of-the-screen-current-web-page-and-browser-window) directly at the time of adding the `<svg>`.

```
d3.select('body').append('svg')
  .attr('width', window.innerWidth)
  .attr('height', window.innerHeight)
```

This wouldn't automatically update if the window was resized, however.