# How do you remove a handler using a d3.js selector

Tags: javascript, jquery, svg, d3.js

I was accidentally overlaying the same event handler on top of svg elements using d3 selectors I was updating.

```
add_listeners = function() {
    d3.selectAll(".nodes").on("click", function() { 
        //Event handler to highlight clicked d3 element
    });

    jQuery('#some_navigation_button').on('click', function() { 
        //Event handler 
    });
    jQuery('#some_refresh_button').on('click', function() { 
        //Event handler that re-draws some d3 svg elements
    });

    //... 5 other navigation and d3 handlers
}
```

The `add_listeners()` was re-adding the same handlers. So I tried

```
add_listeners = function() {
    d3.selectAll(".nodes").off();
    jQuery('#some_navigation_button').off();
    jQuery('#some_refresh_button').off();

    d3.selectAll(".nodes").on("click", function() { 
        //Event handler 
    });
    jQuery('#some_navigation_button').on('click', function() { 
        //Event handler 
    });
    jQuery('#some_refresh_button').on('click', function() { 
        //Event handler that re-draws some d3 svg elements
    });

    //... 5 other navigation and d3 handlers
}
```

, with no luck.

Notes: using d3 v2.9.1 ,

Comment: You mention this is during update. Have you considered only adding your event handlers during only the .enter selection? See [d3 Lifecycle events](https://github.com/misoproject/d3.chart/wiki/available-lifecycle-events)

Comment: Is this common? >>: I have ten other handlers being added in add_listeners() above. Some of them are __not__ on d3.js objects, where `.off()` works. So I was hoping to address this problem uniformly in one place.

Comment: What are the event handlers doing? Are they all on the same selection? Could be excessive but all depends on context.

Comment: Added some more clarity above.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Found out that although `.off()` is not supported for d3 v2.9.1, an alternative is
`.on('click',null)`

Fully:

```
add_listeners = function() {
    // Remove handler before adding, to avoid superfluous handlers on elements.
    d3.selectAll(".nodes").on('click',null);

    d3.selectAll(".nodes").on("click", function() { 
        //Event handler 
    });
}
```

Reference:

https://github.com/d3/d3-selection#selection_on

Comment: It is also worth noting that the [official documentation](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Selections#wiki-on) says: `If an event listener was already registered for the same type on the selected element, the existing listener is removed before the new listener is added.`. So there is actually no need to call `.on('click', null)` as the old event listener will be overwritten.

Comment: but i think we should still do this to avoid the memory leak..what say