# Update Size of D3 Charts Through Updated Variables

Tags: javascript, css, d3.js, svg

First, this: [Resize svg when window is resized in d3.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16265123/resize-svg-when-window-is-resized-in-d3-js) is not what I'm looking for.

My graph width is defined as the following few functions:

```
var element = document.getElementById('front'),
    style = window.getComputedStyle(element),
    divWidth = parseInt(style.getPropertyValue('width'), 10),
    divHeight = parseInt(style.getPropertyValue('height'), 10);
window.onresize = function() {
    divWidth = parseInt(style.getPropertyValue('width'), 10),
    divHeight = parseInt(style.getPropertyValue('height'), 10);
};

var margin = {top: 20, right: 40, bottom: 90, left: 40},
width = divWidth - margin.left - margin.right,
height = divHeight - margin.top - margin.bottom;
```

Which works perfectly when the page is generated. As you can see, the variable is dynamically updated as the screen gets shifted. What I want to know is how to update the width of the chart at the same time as the variable gets reassigned.

Link and source for the project: [Cards](https://secure.scheduleinterpreter.com/bestinterpreters/wip/dashboard/ada/Dashboard/dashboard.005.html)

[Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/HfnIs1PlYcXCTcdHTLHA?p=preview)

---

An additional question after reading up some more: What is the best way to do the alternative to `window.resize` with a div in place of the window.

EDIT: Found a great div resize tool: http://www.backalleycoder.com/2013/03/18/cross-browser-event-based-element-resize-detection/

Comment: It would be very helpful if you could provide a fiddle/plunker with a (small amount of) sample data.

Comment: Also, it's unclear what solution are you looking for. "What I want to know is how to update the width of the chart at the same time as the variable gets reassigned." Is your question D3-related, or do you want to fire an event after some variable gets updated (this is a pure JavaScript question)?

Comment: @DmitriyKhudorozhkov It's d3 related. (I'm currently making a plunker). I need to essentially redraw the graph on resize of the div. You'll see once I include the plunker

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the [polling technique](http://www.backalleycoder.com/2013/03/18/cross-browser-event-based-element-resize-detection/), you can solve the issue in this way:

```
addResizeListener(target, function()
{
    var style = window.getComputedStyle(target);

    divWidth = parseInt(style.getPropertyValue('width'), 10);
    divHeight = parseInt(style.getPropertyValue('height'), 10);

    width = divWidth - margin.left - margin.right;
    height = divHeight - margin.top - margin.bottom;

    document.getElementById('front').innerHTML = '<span style="font-size: 40px; font-family:icons; cursor:pointer" id="flip" onclick="flipper(\'flipper\')"></span>';

    makeTestGraph();
    makeSliderGraph();
});
```

[Working plunker](https://embed.plnkr.co/A8EyNR4EJtKZ6JZEiOiJ/).

Comment: @AlexeyAyzin I can't get your Plunkr to work. I get just an empty divs, so I can't test.

Comment: @AlexeyAyzin also, your plunkr is way to big. Any way you can cut it to just the minimal functionality?

Comment: It's updated now in the post and here: https://plnkr.co/edit/HfnIs1PlYcXCTcdHTLHA?p=preview

Comment: @AlexeyAyzin I've edited my question with the solution; included a link to working plunker.

Comment: What is this line:       document.getElementById('front').innerHTML = '<span style="font-size: 40px; font-family:icons; cursor:pointer" id="flip" onclick="flipper(\'flipper\')"></span>';

Comment: @AlexeyAyzin it resets the "front" container's contents, so graph can be repainted anew.

Comment: Any way to bypass this?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/114048/discussion-between-alexey-ayzin-and-dmitriy-khudorozhkov).

Comment: @AlexeyAyzin this is the easiest way to repaint the graph. If you're concerned that graph repainting is slow - it is because of CSV reading, not because of painting code.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that what you're trying to do can be solved with the [preserveAspectRatio](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/preserveAspectRatio) attribute and a wrapper div. [Here is a blog post on the subject](https://chartio.com/resources/tutorials/how-to-resize-an-svg-when-the-window-is-resized-in-d3-js)

When initializing your svg element, simply set the viewBox and perserveAspectRatio attributes. The element will then become responsive in relation to its immediate parent.

```
 <svg id="chart" width="600" height="200"
   viewBox="<LEFT> <TOP> <WIDTH> <HEIGHT>"
   perserveAspectRatio="xMinYMid[none/etc]">
```

Depending on your need, you may want to use a different scaling rule.

A [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/shawnbot/BJLe6/) credit to Shawn Allen, the author of this snippet.

Comment: Might wanna comment this or at least include some code and details

Comment: @AlexeyAyzin the 1st answer in the topic you linked is about this very attribute: http://stackoverflow.com/a/25978286/2431110

Comment: @DmitriyKhudorozhkov The thing with that is the following: It changes on the window resize, I need it to happen on the div resize