# Resize a d3.js chart

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js, svg

I use `jquery` and `d3.js` to draw a chart inside a message dialog.

How can I resize the `d3.js` chart without redrawing the entire chart?

The current solution works but is really inefficient: http://jsfiddle.net/L6UGn/61/ I did not figure out how to update the width, height without redrawing the entire chart.

My idea was update the width and height of the `svg`. Any idea how to approach it?

```
    d3.select('#msg_dialog > svg') //.selectAll("g")
    .attr('width', width)
    .attr('height', height);
```

Comment: Either you can use the `viewBox` attribute on svg or you can redraw the chart. But `viewBox` may not be able to handle all conditions. So best way is to redraw the chart

Comment: redrawing seems not to be a good idea, because the chart may contain lots of data. as a consequence the redraw will slow down. my updated example uses viewBox: http://jsfiddle.net/L6UGn/62/ is that what you mean? what does the preserveAspectRatio do?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16265123/resize-svg-when-window-is-resized-in-d3-js

Comment: @Arnold `preserveAspectRatio` will do the uniform scale. It will preserve the aspect ratio (width to height ratio). Aso If you are not dealing with aspect ratio then `viewBox` is easiest way to do it. https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/preserveAspectRatio