# Y axis some text cut of in d3js bar chart

Tags: javascript, d3.js, bar-chart

I have a bar chart with d3  which is https://jsfiddle.net/1e87abkz/

and to rotate the text I write

```
.selectAll("text")  
            .style("text-anchor", "end")            
            .attr("dx", "-.8em")
            .attr("dy", ".15em")
            .attr("transform","rotate(-65)")
            .style("font-size","15px");
```

but in bottom some text cut of 
[image]
please suggest how to fix this to visible all text .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just increase your bottom margin to make enough room (line #65 in your fiddle):

```
var margin = { top: 20, right: 30, bottom: 120, left: 40 },
```

Answer (score 1):

Increase the height of your svg to make it visible.

```
<svg id="graph" style="height:700px"></svg>
```

you can also make your svg responsive, see the questions below to do that.

[Resize svg when window is resized in d3.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16265123/resize-svg-when-window-is-resized-in-d3-js)

[Whats the best way to make a d3.js visualisation layout responsive?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9400615/whats-the-best-way-to-make-a-d3-js-visualisation-layout-responsive)

Comment: Thanks for help and suggestion