# responsive D3 chart

Tags: d3.js, responsive-design

I have this D3 chart - pretty much out of the box. Is there a way to make it responsive and use percentages for the width and height variables, innerRadius, and outerRadius? I'm workign on a responsive site and need this to change based on screen size/browser size.

jsfiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/BTfmH/1/

Code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style type="text/css">
html,
body {
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
}

.chart-container {
/*  width:50%;
  height:50%;*/
}
</style>
<body>
<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
<script>
  var width = 350,
      height = 350,
      τ = 2 * Math.PI;

  var arc = d3.svg.arc()
      .innerRadius(100)
      .outerRadius(135)
      .startAngle(0);

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
      .attr("width", width)
      .attr("height", height)
    .append("g")
      .attr("transform", "translate(" + width / 2 + "," + height / 2 + ")")

  var background = svg.append("path")
      .datum({endAngle: τ})
      .style("fill", "green")
      .attr("d", arc);

  var foreground = svg.append("path")
    .datum({endAngle: .127 * τ})
      .style("fill", "grey")
      .attr("d", arc);

setInterval(function() {
  foreground.transition()
      .duration(750)
      .call(arcTween, Math.random() * τ);
}, 1500);

  function arcTween(transition, newAngle) {

    transition.attrTween("d", function(d) {

      var interpolate = d3.interpolate(d.endAngle, newAngle);

      return function(t) {

        d.endAngle = interpolate(t);

        return arc(d);
      };
    });
}
</script>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Whats the best way to make a d3.js visualisation layout responsive?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9400615/whats-the-best-way-to-make-a-d3-js-visualisation-layout-responsive)

Answer (score 142, accepted):

You can make the chart resize using a combination of `viewBox` and `preserveAspectRatio` attributes on the SVG element.

See this jsfiddle for the full example: http://jsfiddle.net/BTfmH/12/

```
var svg = d3.select('.chart-container').append("svg")
    .attr("width", '100%')
    .attr("height", '100%')
    .attr('viewBox','0 0 '+Math.min(width,height)+' '+Math.min(width,height))
    .attr('preserveAspectRatio','xMinYMin')
    .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + Math.min(width,height) / 2 + "," + Math.min(width,height) / 2 + ")");
```

You won't even need a `resize` handler with this method.

Comment: THANKS so much for help on this! I especially appreciate this since it was unanswered / idle for so long!

Comment: @TechyDude, No problem—I needed this myself and saw your question. I couldn't find a good answer elsewhere so extended your example.

Comment: @SamSehnert , Thanks for the answer, I have done something similar here in https://jsfiddle.net/adityap16/11edxrnq/1/ . But when i am porting it in React my plots are becoming really small, Can you think of any reason why?

Comment: My superstar incarnate!

Comment: Thanks @SamSehnert

Answer (score 6):

You can use `window.innerWidth` and `window.innerHeight` to get the dimensions of the screen and set up your graph accordingly, e.g.

```
var width = window.innerWidth,
    height = window.innerHeight,
    innerRadius = Math.min(width,height)/3,
    outerRadius = innerRadius + 30;
```

Comment: Thanks for your response Lars! That does definitely work in terms of sizing the charts based on the window page. How would I make it resize with the browser window?

Comment: You can use the `onresize` event (see e.g. [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/641857/javascript-window-resize-event)) but you would have to redraw yourself.