# How do I make the d3 zoomable treemap responsive?

Tags: svg, d3.js, responsive-design, treemap

I'm trying to create a responsive version of the [zoomable treemap example](http://mbostock.github.io/d3/talk/20111018/treemap.html). What needs to be added so that the treemap resizes with the window?

When I try to change `treemap.size()` in an update method on `$(window).resize()`, nothing seems to happen.

I'm setting the svg to `style="width: 100%; height: 100%"` and the svg resizes, but the layout of the treemap does not. I also tried using `viewbox` and `preserveAspectRatio` [per this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19379852/784553) and the treemap looks initially correct, however the zooming functionality no longer works correctly because the `treemap` layout doesn't know its correct size.

Comment: You would, after setting the size of the treemap, have to redraw it (at least on zoom).

Comment: What's the best way to redraw?

Comment: Just as you're drawing it the first time, you would have to set the attributes of all the elements.

Answer (score 1):

One way to handle this is as [Lars Kotthoff](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1172002/lars-kotthoff) told you can redraw the treemap.

For that first you should specify the width and height parameters as your graph containers width and height before that you should specify container width and height in percentage. And wrap the zoomable map drwing script inside a function (Let's call it as zoomabletreemap())

Then you should call the zoomabletreemap() function for the window resize event using JavaScript. Before calling the javascript you should remove the old graph also.

```
$(window).resize(function () {
            var div = document.getElementById("my-svg-div"); //id of the div we are appending to the chart container to contain the svg
            div.parentNode.removeChild(div);
            ZoomableTreeMap();
            });
```

[Here is the working example](http://jsfiddle.net/rameezvly/bty4X/2/) for the same I explained above