# Increasing click radius for mobile users?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I've developed a game and interactive learning tool about epidemics. It's been implemented with D3js' force-directed graph layout.

During development, I hadn't planned for much enthusiasm from mobile users. In hindsight, this was a glaring miscalculation.

Is there a way to increase the range of an "acceptable click" for mobile users? Or am I stuck with increasing the node size after I've detected a user is on a mobile platform?

Example: http://vax.herokuapp.com

Comment: You could put your nodes into larger transparent circles that react to click/tap, or have a global event handler that determines whether the current event position is close enough to a node.

Comment: Thanks, I've looked into a few methods to resolve this problem. It seems like your solution is the simplest. Is there a way to bind/handle these objects as one element?

Comment: Use a `g` element that contains both to bind the data to.

Comment: perfect! Thank you! It's not like you're in need of SO reputation, but you should submit an answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could put your nodes into larger transparent circles that react to click/tap. If you put both circles into the same `g` element and bind the data to that, the additional code would be minimal.

```
var gs = d3.selectAll("g").data(data).enter();
gs.append("circle").attr("cx", ...).attr("r", 5);
gs.append("circle").attr("cx", ...).attr("r", 40).attr("opacity", 0)
  .on("click", function() { ... });
```

Comment: Worked like a charm. It'll go live as soon as traffic dies down.

Answer (score 0):

You should make your drawing responsive to mobile layout. A simple way is to adjust viewbox size:

[Whats the best way to make a d3.js visualisation layout responsive?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9400615/whats-the-best-way-to-make-a-d3-js-visualisation-layout-responsive/9404537#9404537)

Comment: Thanks, I've done some work with the viewbox for dynamic window resizing, but I've had trouble implementing it with all browsers. I'm in the process of detecting for mobile devices and limiting the number of nodes as well.