# How to make a stream graph responsive (d3.js)?

Tags: javascript, graph, d3.js, responsive-design, stream-graph

I'm making a stream graph using d3.js for my company, and I'm wondering how to make it responsive. My code isn't much different from this example: http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4060954

[image]

I've been playing with setting `viewBox="0 0 height width"` and `preserveAspectRatio = "xMinYMid meet"` to no avail.

Any suggestions?

Comment: What do you mean by responsive?  Could you create a jsfiddle or post the code you're working with?

Comment: I think she means making the SVG scale when the container is resized.

Comment: Have you seen [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9400615/whats-the-best-way-to-make-a-d3-js-visualisation-layout-responsive)?

Comment: @HenrikHelmers, yes that's exactly what I meant.

Comment: @THK I meant I should be able to resize the window, and the svg should  scale and maintain proportions. Normally, I would work with svg in a percentage context. So, d3 is throwing me through a loop since the height and width are used in the math. I didn't make a fiddle, because it would have been redundant. Only a trivial difference between mine and that mbostock example. Notice, that example does not resize well.

Comment: @LarsKotthoff that jsfiddle did the exact trick! Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So, solution for this problem was this jsfiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/shawnbot/BJLe6/
specifically, this code:

```
var chart = $("#chart"),
aspect = chart.width() / chart.height(),
container = chart.parent();

$(window).on("resize", function() {
var targetWidth = container.width();
chart.attr("width", targetWidth);
chart.attr("height", Math.round(targetWidth / aspect));
}).trigger("resize");
```

Thanks to everyone who helped!