# D3 circle packing diameter calculation

Tags: d3.js, circle-pack

I am using the pack layout for packing different no of equal sized circles. I have a group of clusters to be visualized. So I am calling pack function for each cluster of circles. In all the d3 examples the diameter is either calculated with the given size or fixed diameter. I would like to calculate it according to the no of circles to be packed. So how do I calculate the packing circle diameter?
is there any formula so that I can pack the circles without wasting the space.

Answer (score 0):

If you truly don't care about relative sizing of the circles, then you could make your JSON file represent only the data you care about(say, names) and feed your packing function a dummy value that the 'value' accessor function is expecting.

For instance:

```
var circleChildren = [{
    "value": 1
}, {
    "value": 1
}, {
    "value": 1
}, {
    "value": 1
}];
```

would give you a JSON object that you can use as children for your packing function:

```
var circleInput = Object();
circleInput.children = circleChildren;
```

You can verify that in your console by running:

```
bubble.nodes(circleInput)
    .filter(function (d) {
    return !d.children; //we're flattening the 'parent-child' node structure
})
```

where `bubble` is your D3 packing bubble variable.
[Here's a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/66e6N/) that demonstrates that. It may have some extra things but it implements what you're looking for. In addition, you can play around with the number of circles by adding more dummies in the JSON file, as well as changing the SVG container size in the `diameter` variable. Hope that helps!

EDIT: The size of your layout(in this case, a misnomer of the 'diameter' variable) directly determines the size and diameter of your circles within. At some point you have to assign the pack.size() or pack.radius() value in order for your circles to display within a layout([documentation](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Pack-Layout#wiki-size) ):

> If size is specified, sets the available layout size to the specified two-element array of numbers representing x and y. If size is not specified, returns the current size, which defaults to 1×1.

Here you have several options:

1. If you want your circles to be 'dynamically' sized to your available element's width (that is, if you want them to cover up all the element width available) then I'd recommend you get your element's width beforehand, and then apply in your pack() function. The problem is then you have to think about resizing, etc.
2. If you want to keep the maximum sizing available, then you have to make your viz responsive. There's a really good [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9400615/whats-the-best-way-to-make-a-d3-js-visualisation-layout-responsive) already in SO that deals with that.

I know this isn't the full solution but hopefully that points you in the right direction for what you're trying to do.

FURTHER EDIT:

All of a sudden, another idea came to mind. Kind of an implementation of my previous suggestion, but this would ensure you're using the maximum space available at the time for your circle drawing:

```
zone = d3.select("#myDiv");
myWidth = zone.style("width").substring(0, zone.style("width").length - 2);
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer but you still give diameter as 300 in the fiddle. I want to calculate the diameter and not fix it. If you can help me there then it would be great!