# 2dimple.js/d3.js auto size chart when window size changes

Tags: javascript, d3.js, dimple.js

I have the following code that draws a chart using dimple.js: http://jsbin.com/zacus/17/
When the browser window is resized (or the jsbin pane is resized) i want the chart to also resize to fit it's table cell parent.  As you can see from the example this does not happen.
I have attempted writing an event handler to change the width of the chart or to redraw the chart when it's , but to no avail.

```
window.onresize= function redraw(){
  chart1.setBounds(70, 30, pTd.offsetWidth-150, 300);
  myLegend1.left = chart1.width + 100;
}
```

Any suggestions on how to accomplish this?

EDIT:  Experimenting a bit led me to the following code which seems to solve my problem. Is this the best way to accomplish this?

```
chart1.svg.attr("width", "100%")
  .attr("height", "100%")
  .attr("viewBox", "0 0 600 400");
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9400615/whats-the-best-way-to-make-a-d3-js-visualisation-layout-responsive

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I haven't tried it with viewBox so if that's working it sounds a good solution.  I do it using `setMargins` for the proportions of the chart and calling `chart.draw` on resize.  This has the benefit of using dimples sizing logic - for example rotating x axis labels when the chart gets too small.

Here's an example from the website:

```
// Set up a standard chart
var myChart;
d3.tsv("/data/example_data.tsv", function (data) {
    myChart = new dimple.chart(svg, data);

    // Fix the margins
    myChart.setMargins("60px", "30px", "110px", "70px");

    // Continue to set up a standard chart
    myChart.addCategoryAxis("x", "Month").addOrderRule("Date");
    myChart.addMeasureAxis("y", "Unit Sales");
    myChart.addSeries("Channel", dimple.plot.bar);

    // Set the legend using negative values to set the co-ordinate from the right
    myChart.addLegend("-100px", "30px", "100px", "-70px");
    myChart.draw();
});

// Add a method to draw the chart on resize of the window
window.onresize = function () {
    // As of 1.1.0 the second parameter here allows you to draw
    // without reprocessing data.  This saves a lot on performance
    // when you know the data won't have changed.
    myChart.draw(0, true);
};
```

[Here it is in action](http://dimplejs.org/advanced_examples_viewer.html?id=advanced_responsive_sizing)

Comment: I tried this solution with the example mentioned:  (http://jsbin.com/zacus/17/), but the size of the chart remains the same when i resize the window

Comment: Are you using setBounds?  You either need to use setBounds with percentage sizes, or setMargins to have the chart size according to the SVG.

Comment: I tried both of those and for the life of me can't figure out why it won't work.  i do have my chart in a table with width set to 100%. Wondering if that might have anything to do with it.  here is an example: http://jsbin.com/zacus/47/edit?html,js,output

Comment: i think my issue was that i was not using 100% height and width when creating the SVG.  Your example made that clear.  Thanks! dimple.newSvg("#chartContainer", "100%", "100%");

Comment: dimple.newSvg("#chartContainer", "100%", "100%"); AND myChart.draw(0, true); work together. Thanks

Comment: Be careful that `resize` event could be called several times according to browser type