# In d3.js how to create a dynamic scale value for projection?

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js

Am beginner for `d3.js`. I create a `geomap` with using `d3.js`.My map is working fine but i have some problem in `scaling`.

I need to display my map with full screen of the window.

So i created with using below code.

```
  // Html Part
  <div id="world-placeholder" style="width:100%;height:auto;">

  </div>

  // Script part for generating SVG
  <script>

        var svg = d3.select('#'+id)
                  .append('svg');

        // Set Width & Hight
        var width = $("svg").parent().width();      
        var height = width/2;                       

        // Set Projection
        var projection = d3.geo.robinson()
            //.scale(100)
            //.scale((width/height)*100)
            .translate([width/2, height/2]);

        // Set Path
        var path = d3.geo.path()        
            .projection(projection);
</script>
```

Basically am trying to plot the map with using current width of the screen by using `$("svg").parent().width();`

So my question is how to stretch my map with full screen.

### Result screen Before Scaling (Not used any scaling)

[image: Before Scaling]

### Result Screen After Scaling (Used scale(200) for stretching)

[image: After Scaling]

**Scaling Code Part**

```
  var projection = d3.geo.robinson()
            .scale(200)
            .translate([width/2, height/2]);
```

How to Scale dynamically based on window size? or any other way to display a map with full screen for all devices?

Please help me to solve.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Whats the best way to make a d3.js visualisation layout responsive?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9400615/whats-the-best-way-to-make-a-d3-js-visualisation-layout-responsive)

Answer (score 0):

I use something like this for screen size :

```
var GUIWidth = window.innerWidth; //-screen width
var GUIHeight = window.innerHeight; //-screen height
```

Maybe creating a JSFiddle would help people solve your problem easier :)

Answer (score 0):

You can even use: 
`document.getElementById("cont").clientHeight and  document.getElementById("cont").clientHeight` 
 for calculating dynamic width and height of your container. In this case "cont" is a div with 100% height and width.