# How to make a d3js histogram chart responsive

Tags: d3.js, responsive-design

I've written this chart which is fine, very straightforward but not responsive which it has to be.
I've tried a few things no luck. I'm not an expert on d3js.

https://jsfiddle.net/a2zr20ep/14/

I tried the below but it didn't work.

```
/*window resize operations*/
function resize() {
  console.log('----resize function----');
  // update width
  width = parseInt(d3.select('#chartID').style('width'), 10);
  width = width - margin.left - margin.right;

  height = parseInt(d3.select("#chartID").style("height"));
  height = height - margin.top - margin.bottom;
  console.log('----resiz width----'+width);
  console.log('----resiz height----'+height);
  // resize the chart
  xScale.rangeRoundBands([0, width], .1);
  yScale.range([height+100, 0]);

  yAxis.ticks(Math.max(height/50, 2));
  xAxis.ticks(Math.max(width/50, 2));

  d3.select(svgContainer.node().parentNode)
      .style('width', (width + margin.left + margin.right) + 'px');

  svgContainer.selectAll('.g')
      .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + xScale(d.name) + ",0)"; });

  svgContainer.selectAll("rect")
      .attr("x",function(d) { return d.name; })
      .attr("width", xScale.rangeBand());

  svgContainer.select('.x.axis').call(xAxis.orient('bottom')).selectAll("text").attr('dy','0.5em').attr('dx','-3em'); 
}
```

Comment: See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9400615/whats-the-best-way-to-make-a-d3-js-visualisation-layout-responsive).

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to scale your chart, SVG is scalable (vector graphics).
It is possible to set a [viewBox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/viewBox) and a [preserveAspectRatio](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/preserveAspectRatio) attribute on the SVG element.

If you set these both and apply a with in relative units like %, the SVG just scales with your site without a need to rerender the chart via js.

I actually just pushed a [d3 chart template](https://github.com/jhinzmann/D3ReusableResponsiveChartTemplate) to github where i use this approach.

I forked your fiddle and added the `viewbox`, `preserveAspectRatio` and a width of `100%`. When you resize the pane, the chart resizes. See [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/a2zr20ep/16/)

Comment: Hi there, your jsfiddle was good and thank you so much, I'm not an expert at d3js, but your solution I will study and learn from as d3 is the way to go. d3js has to promote ALL their charts for responsiveness now or else they're toast - again a big thanks for my pestering.     Andy

Comment: Glad that i could help you ;) if my answer solved your problem, please  mark  it as  accepted answer. That way it is clear that your question was solved and others can see  which answer solved your problem