# How to create responsive svg using d3.js

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg, d3.js

I need my SVG in a webpage to dynamically resize based on window size, or to have multiple hardcoded widths and heights.

I am using the D3 library.

My problem is that it isn't just the SVG tag that needs a different canvas size, it is the children elements such as a `rect` tag and `g` tag that also need to resize or be completely re-rendered

How would this be done?

I realize I could listen to window resizing with

`d3.select(window).on('resize', resize);`

with my resize function doing all the logic, but exactly how and what width/heights to choose (or calculate) is beyond me

```
<div class="svg-container">
<svg width="960" height="500" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid" class="svg-content">
   <defs>
     <clipPath id="clip-upper">
      <rect id="rect-clip-upper" width="960" height="305" x="-480" y="-305">      </rect>
</clipPath>
<clipPath id="clip-lower">
  <rect id="rect-clip-lower" width="960" height="195" x="-480" y="0"></rect>
</clipPath>
</defs>
   <g clip-path="url(#clip-upper)" transform="translate(480,305)"></g>
   <g clip-path="url(#clip-lower)" transform="translate(480,305)"></g>
 </svg>
```

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9400615/whats-the-best-way-to-make-a-d3-js-visualisation-layout-responsive

Comment: @LarsKotthoff thanks! I had searched on the net for a few solutions, which were not working for my use case, and stackoverflow didn't even suggest relevant ones like that question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you add a viewBox to the svg element e.g. viewBox="0 0 960 500" you won't need to resize any children.

Comment: ah I saw that but I didn't realize this benefit over modifying the html style width and height selectors, I will give this a shot!

Comment: width and height is the size of the drawing, viewBox is the size of the contents.

Comment: I did this and ended up simply using the @media css attribute and declaring certain sizes

Answer (score 1):

Instead of hardcoding a width, make it dependent upon the width of the parent of the svg. E.g.

```
width = svgParent[0][0].clientWidth - margin.left - margin.right;
height = svgParent[0][0].clientHeight - margin.top - margin.bottom;
```

Make sure that all your widths, heights, and positions are either calculated from data (in which case d3 will handle it) or relate to width/height in some way. Then, in your resize handler, just call `child.attr("width", newWidth)`, `child.attr("x", newX)`, etc. on all elements you want to resize.

If you're using axes, set the range to your new width value and call the axis function again (i.e. `svg.select(".x.axis").call(xAxis)`). If you are using zoom  or other similar features, you'll have to call them again.

Answer (score 1):

Hi SVG it self suggest "Salable vector graphics" so it is responsive by nature so for that you just need to use **"viewBox"** attribute of `<svg>` element. with your perspective use.