# Responsive grouped bar chart in d3js with responsive scale values

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js, charts

I am following this [example](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3887051) to create grouped bar chart. But the chart lacks responsiveness. I want to run it dynamically in all kinds of devices. I want to make it look something like the below chart(not same as chart above copied from an example of a responsive chart):

[image]

And also in above example the x-axis range is overlapped is it possible to make it tilted to so that all values are clear something like below pic so that all x axis range values are displayed.
[image]

The responsiveness of the chart is fixed however the scale values overlap on each other and instead of overlapping I want them all to adjust and appear.

Comment: Maybe this question is useful to you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9400615/whats-the-best-way-to-make-a-d3-js-visualisation-layout-responsive

Comment: Ok I tried that but the bars then become lines and the letters in the axis range are overlapped and not distinguishable , is there any way to tilt the axis range as shown in above figure where chocolate ,vanilla and Strawberry are tilted to accommodate space in mobile view .

Comment: Now I am able to properly display chart in a responsive manner but how to make the scale values responsive. So that they wont overlap on each other.

Comment: Probably you can found a lot of interesting resources googleing "responsive d3.js charts"...