# How to make a responsive canvas animation using the D3 library

Tags: javascript, html, css, canvas, d3.js

I'm developing a simple animation using d3.js library and show it through canvas, but my canvas isn't responsive.

In the beginning of the code, I set original width to 960 and height to 500, but how can I make it resizable (responsive)? I'm not using CSS to apply some style (width and height) to the canvas, I'm using JavaScript to do it. The solution can be CSS or JavaScript.

```js
var width = 960,
    height = 500,
    τ = 2 * Math.PI,
    gravity = .05;

var sample = poissonDiscSampler(width, height, 30),
    nodes = [{
        x: 0,
        y: 0
    }],
    s;

while (s = sample()) nodes.push(s);

var force = d3.layout.force()
    .size([width, height])
    .nodes(nodes.slice())
    .gravity(0)
    .charge(function(d, i) {
        return i ? -30 : -3000;
    })
    .on("tick", ticked)
    .start();

var voronoi = d3.geom.voronoi()
    .x(function(d) {
        return d.x;
    })
    .y(function(d) {
        return d.y;
    });

var root = nodes.shift();

root.fixed = true;

var links = voronoi.links(nodes);

var canvas = d3.select("#canvas").append("canvas")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height)
    .on("ontouchstart" in document ? "touchmove" : "mousemove", moved);

var context = canvas.node().getContext("2d");



function moved() {
    var p1 = d3.mouse(this);
    root.px = p1[0];
    root.py = p1[1];
    force.resume();
}

function ticked() {
    force.resume();

    for (var i = 0, n = nodes.length; i < n; ++i) {
        var node = nodes[i];
        node.y += (node.cy - node.y) * gravity;
        node.x += (node.cx - node.x) * gravity;
    }

    context.clearRect(0, 0, width, height);

    context.beginPath();
    for (var i = 0, n = links.length; i < n; ++i) {
        var link = links[i];
        context.moveTo(link.source.x, link.source.y);
        context.lineTo(link.target.x, link.target.y);
    }
    context.lineWidth = 1;
    context.strokeStyle = "#bbb";
    context.stroke();

    context.beginPath();
    for (var i = 0, n = nodes.length; i < n; ++i) {
        var node = nodes[i];
        context.moveTo(node.x, node.y);
        context.arc(node.x, node.y, 2, 0, τ);
    }
    context.lineWidth = 3;
    context.strokeStyle = "#fff";
    context.stroke();
    context.fillStyle = "#000";
    context.fill();
}

// Based on https://www.jasondavies.com/poisson-disc/
function poissonDiscSampler(width, height, radius) {
    var k = 30, // maximum number of samples before rejection
        radius2 = radius * radius,
        R = 3 * radius2,
        cellSize = radius * Math.SQRT1_2,
        gridWidth = Math.ceil(width / cellSize),
        gridHeight = Math.ceil(height / cellSize),
        grid = new Array(gridWidth * gridHeight),
        queue = [],
        queueSize = 0,
        sampleSize = 0;

    return function() {
        if (!sampleSize) return sample(Math.random() * width, Math.random() * height);

        // Pick a random existing sample and remove it from the queue.
        while (queueSize) {
            var i = Math.random() * queueSize | 0,
                s = queue[i];

            // Make a new candidate between [radius, 2 * radius] from the existing sample.
            for (var j = 0; j < k; ++j) {
                var a = 2 * Math.PI * Math.random(),
                    r = Math.sqrt(Math.random() * R + radius2),
                    x = s.x + r * Math.cos(a),
                    y = s.y + r * Math.sin(a);

                // Reject candidates that are outside the allowed extent,
                // or closer than 2 * radius to any existing sample.
                if (0 <= x && x < width && 0 <= y && y < height && far(x, y)) return sample(x, y);
            }

            queue[i] = queue[--queueSize];
            queue.length = queueSize;
        }
    };

    function far(x, y) {
        var i = x / cellSize | 0,
            j = y / cellSize | 0,
            i0 = Math.max(i - 2, 0),
            j0 = Math.max(j - 2, 0),
            i1 = Math.min(i + 3, gridWidth),
            j1 = Math.min(j + 3, gridHeight);

        for (j = j0; j < j1; ++j) {
            var o = j * gridWidth;
            for (i = i0; i < i1; ++i) {
                if (s = grid[o + i]) {
                    var s,
                        dx = s.x - x,
                        dy = s.y - y;
                    if (dx * dx + dy * dy < radius2) return false;
                }
            }
        }

        return true;
    }

    function sample(x, y) {
        var s = {
            x: x,
            y: y,
            cx: x,
            cy: y
        };
        queue.push(s);
        grid[gridWidth * (y / cellSize | 0) + (x / cellSize | 0)] = s;
        ++sampleSize;
        ++queueSize;
        return s;
    }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
<section>

    <div id="canvas">

    </div>

</section>
```

Comment: Are you saying you don't want to use CSS or javascript to achieve this? What does that last sentence mean?

Comment: @HeadCode No, If have solution with js or css are welcome

Comment: The d3  library on its own will accomplish this for you no need to use canvas

Comment: @markE How it works? I don't know.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Whats the best way to make a d3.js visualisation layout responsive?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9400615/whats-the-best-way-to-make-a-d3-js-visualisation-layout-responsive)

Answer (score 1):

Canvas is like an image. It has it's own physical dimensions but can still be scaled with CSS. Use the `width` and `height` attributes to set the physical dimensions and then use CSS to scale it with a `%` to make it responsive.

Example...

```js
var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
ctx.rect(20, 20, 150, 100);
ctx.stroke();
```

```html
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="300" height="150" style="width:100%;"></canvas>
```

Comment: the problem in this case is cause the javascript file that set width and height and it overrides all css

Comment: @coreid - as demonstrated in the example, the canvas width and height do not override css width and height. they are two different things and they are intended to be used together.

Comment: in other words, all you have to do to make the canvas responsive (regardless of the canvas' width and height ) is to set a width (using CSS) to a percentage. just add `style='width:100%;'` to the canvas itself and it will be responsive.

Comment: I undestand you! But i created a css style for it. set `width: 100%` and `height: 500px;` but, only works because js file overrides everthing

Comment: @coreid - please make a fiddle demonstrating this.