# How to zoom a Canvas drawing

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html5-canvas

I'm trying to zoom in or out my canvas drawing, but if I only scale the context nothing happens.
Do I need to re-draw it after the scale? Is there any method to scale directly the context without drawing it every time I try to zoom in or out?

**PS**: I want to zoom in and out with an HTML5 `<input type="range">` controlled by a script, and that's already working.

Comment: Yes, you have to redraw it every time. There's no way of getting around this. This is actually a good thing because it allows you to perform lots of transforms on the canvas without redrawing every time. If it did, high-intensity games and animations wouldn't be possible.

Comment: no, you certainly don't have to redraw it everytime. leave the width and height attributes alone and use css to scale/"zoom" the entire thing.

Comment: Like this: https://jsfiddle.net/43ejq0op/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like Mike said, the best solution is to redraw it. 
Zooming in with css is a solution, but there's a big loss in quality.

Answer (score 0):

I'm copying my answer from another [question I already answered today](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39857006/how-to-make-a-responsive-canvas-animation-using-the-d3-library/39857473#39857473)..

Canvas is like an image. It has it's own physical dimensions but can still be scaled with CSS. Use the `width` and `height` attributes to set the physical dimensions and then use CSS to scale it with a `%` to <strike>make it responsive</strike> zoom it.

Example...

```js
var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
ctx.rect(20, 20, 150, 100);
ctx.stroke();
```

```html
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="300" height="150" style="width:100%;"></canvas>
```

Here is an overly simplified example: https://jsfiddle.net/43ejq0op/

Comment: This does work but, as you can see in your example, leads to ugly pixelization. If that doesn't matter then it's a great solution. Otherwise, OP will have to re-draw the whole scene (or at least the subset that has been scaled)