# How can i make this d3 chart responsive?

Tags: d3.js

I have to make this d3 chart responsive. I am using

```
 var svg = d3.select("div#container")
.append("svg")
.attr("preserveAspectRatio", "xMinYMin meet")
.attr("viewBox", "0 0 300 300")
.classed("svg-content", true);
```

and the class has

```
 .svg-content {
display: inline-block;
position: absolute;
top: 0;
left: 0;
}
```

But it doesnot seem to work.
Here's the working fiddle
https://jsfiddle.net/84hp8m6p/1/

Comment: Your fiddle doesn't set a `viewBox`! Try adding that and set `width` and `height` to some relative values and you are done.

Comment: Works for me: https://jsfiddle.net/84hp8m6p/4/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Whats the best way to make a d3.js visualisation layout responsive?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9400615/whats-the-best-way-to-make-a-d3-js-visualisation-layout-responsive)