# D3 SVG doesn't resize responsively

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

I'm just getting to grips with D3 and wanted to make it resize as you resize the window, I managed to do it through some javascript which is commented out in the below example, but there is a [thread here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9400615/whats-the-best-way-to-make-a-d3-js-visualisation-layout-responsive) which says that width and height can be left off the SVG element and it will resize responsively without javascript. Sadly this doesn't work for me and I'm testing with IE11 and Firefox latest.

1. When I leave off width and height it only shows text

   ```
               **width="960" height="500"**
   ```
2. When I uncomment the JS at the bottom it works
3. When I include width and height the size doesn't change with window size

The snippet is below but doesn't work because I'm using D3 version 4 and JQ version 3.x, the snippet tool only seems to allow earlier versions.

How can I make it resize without the javascript being uncommented?

I'm sure this is something daft and obvious but I've been stuck on it for ages !.. thanks

```js
        $(function () {
            var svg = d3.select("svg"),
                width = +svg.attr("width"),
                height = +svg.attr("height"),
                radius = Math.min(width, height) / 2,
                g = svg.append("g").attr("transform", "translate(" + width / 2 + "," + height / 2 + ")");

            var color = d3.scaleOrdinal(["#98abc5", "#8a89a6", "#7b6888", "#6b486b", "#a05d56", "#d0743c", "#ff8c00"]);

            var pie = d3.pie()
                .sort(null)
                .value(function (d) { return d.population; });

            var path = d3.arc()
                .outerRadius(radius - 10)
                .innerRadius(0);

            var label = d3.arc()
                .outerRadius(radius - 40)
                .innerRadius(radius - 40);

            d3.csv("data.csv", function (d) {
                d.population = +d.population;
                return d;
            }, function (error, data) {
                if (error) throw error;

                var arc = g.selectAll(".arc")
                  .data(pie(data))
                  .enter().append("g")
                    .attr("class", "arc");

                arc.append("path")
                    .attr("d", path)
                    .attr("fill", function (d) { return color(d.data.age); });

                arc.append("text")
                    .attr("transform", function (d) { return "translate(" + label.centroid(d) + ")"; })
                    .attr("dy", "0.35em")
                    .text(function (d) { return d.data.age; });
            });

            // Uncomment this to make it resize with the window width changes

            //var aspect = width / height,
            //    chart = d3.select('svg');
            //d3.select(window)
            //  .on("resize", function () {
            //      var targetWidth = $(window).width();
            //      chart.attr("width", targetWidth);
            //      chart.attr("height", targetWidth / aspect);
            //  });


        });
```

```css
        svg {
            display: inline-block;
            position: absolute;
            top: 0;
            left: 0;
        }

        body {
            display: inline-block;
            position: relative;
            width: 100%;
            vertical-align: middle;
            background-color:#ffffe0;
        }
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"
    integrity="sha256-hwg4gsxgFZhOsEEamdOYGBf13FyQuiTwlAQgxVSNgt4="
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<svg width="960" height="500" viewBox="0 0 900 600" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet"></svg>
```

data.csv:

```
age,population
<5,2704659
5-13,4499890
14-17,2159981
18-24,3853788
25-44,14106543
45-64,8819342
=65,612463
```

Comment: Could you please give an example of your data.csv

Comment: Yes, sorry, it was grabbed from an online example:

Comment: I'll edit the question to add it

Comment: Your snippet isn't even executable! Your code uses D3 **v4** whereas you are referencing D3 **v3.4.11**.

Comment: I think I've fixed the cdn links, but it still won't work because data.csv doesn't exist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you leave off width and height attributes, you can't expect to read them with `svg.attr("width")`. What you really want to get is the viewBox *property* width and height:

```
    $(function () {
        var svg = d3.select("svg"),
            width = svg.property("viewBox").baseVal.width,
            height = svg.property("viewBox").baseVal.height,
            radius = Math.min(width, height) / 2,
            g = svg.append("g").attr("transform", "translate(" + width / 2 + "," + height / 2 + ")");

    //...
    });
```

Comment: Thanks - thats obviously a step in the right direction, but still not working. I'm messing around with it now to see whats up.

Comment: Are you on IE11 right now? I've tested only with FF so far.

Comment: Aha ! FF works - thats cool. I'm not too worried about IE. OK thanks for your efforts here